# No me pone valor recogido dentro de un input

Tags: php, javascript

Lo que pasa es que quiero recoger datos de un campo llamado email de una tabla para luego meterlo en un valor input.

Ok selecciono la tabla, y extraigo el campo email mediante un bucle while. Y luego mediante un print_r logrando sacar del while la variable que contiene el resultado de la consulta lo se porque logré hacerle un testeo y si me lo mostro,pero lo quiere incluir en un input del formulario values = .
Pero se pierde el valor y ya no puedo procesar el formulario.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  // output data of each row

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


$email = $row['email'];



  }

} else {

    

}
?>
```

```
<?
//Testeando fuera del bucle 
print_r($email); 
Y si me muestra su valor
?>
```

pero al ponerlo dentro del formulario no me pone ningún valor y quiero que me ponga el correo que recogí ejemplo@correo.com

```
 <input name="email" type="text" value= "<?php print_r($email); ?>
```

Comment: ¿ Te aseguraste de poner " <?php " en lugar de solo " <? " ?

Comment: Intenta con este y me dejas saber `<input name="email" type="text" value= "<?php print_r($email); ?> " />`

Comment: Einer Me lo muestra vacío.

Comment: Ya logré ponerlo en un input value.